# Entity Framework composing SQL in unexpected order

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a query that must get the top 15 items from a ordered query that fulfill some details. So I was doing something like:

```
var ten = repository
            .Orders
            .OrderByDescending(p => p.ClerkCode)
            .Select(o=>o.OrderId)
            .Take(10)
            ;

var orders = repository
                .Orders
                .Where(o => ten.Contains(o.OrderId))
                .Include(o => o.Products);
```

So the subquery gets all the items that qualifies, and main query just completes the information. This generates the following query:

```
SELECT
[Project2].[OrderId] AS [OrderId],
[Project2].[CustomerId] AS [CustomerId],
[Project2].[ClerkCode] AS [ClerkCode],
[Project2].[C1] AS [C1],
[Project2].[ProductOrderId] AS [ProductOrderId],
[Project2].[ProductId] AS [ProductId],
[Project2].[OrderId1] AS [OrderId1],
[Project2].[Quantity] AS [Quantity]
FROM ( SELECT
    [Extent1].[OrderId] AS [OrderId],
    [Extent1].[CustomerId] AS [CustomerId],
    [Extent1].[ClerkCode] AS [ClerkCode],
    [Extent2].[ProductOrderId] AS [ProductOrderId],
    [Extent2].[ProductId] AS [ProductId],
    [Extent2].[OrderId] AS [OrderId1],
    [Extent2].[Quantity] AS [Quantity],
    CASE WHEN ([Extent2].[ProductOrderId] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) ELSE 1 END AS [C1]
    FROM  [dbo].[Orders] AS [Extent1]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[ProductOrders] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[OrderId] = [Extent2].[OrderId]
    WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT
        1 AS [C1]
        FROM ( SELECT TOP (10) [Extent3].[OrderId] AS [OrderId]
            FROM [dbo].[Orders] AS [Extent3]
            ORDER BY [Extent3].[ClerkCode] DESC
        )  AS [Limit1]
        WHERE [Limit1].[OrderId] = [Extent1].[OrderId]
    )
)  AS [Project2]
ORDER BY [Project2].[OrderId] ASC, [Project2].[C1] ASC
```

I can see is doing the `select top` on an ordered subquery.

Now comes the problem. I want to take 10 distinct items, so I change my query to this:

```
var ten = repository
            .Orders
            .OrderByDescending(p => p.ClerkCode)
            .Select(o=>o.OrderId)
            .Distinct()
            .Take(10)
            ;

var orders = repository
                .Orders
                .Where(o => ten.Contains(o.OrderId))
                .Include(o => o.Products);
```

And now the generated SQL is like this:

```
SELECT
[Project2].[OrderId] AS [OrderId],
[Project2].[CustomerId] AS [CustomerId],
[Project2].[ClerkCode] AS [ClerkCode],
[Project2].[C1] AS [C1],
[Project2].[ProductOrderId] AS [ProductOrderId],
[Project2].[ProductId] AS [ProductId],
[Project2].[OrderId1] AS [OrderId1],
[Project2].[Quantity] AS [Quantity]
FROM ( SELECT
    [Extent1].[OrderId] AS [OrderId],
    [Extent1].[CustomerId] AS [CustomerId],
    [Extent1].[ClerkCode] AS [ClerkCode],
    [Extent2].[ProductOrderId] AS [ProductOrderId],
    [Extent2].[ProductId] AS [ProductId],
    [Extent2].[OrderId] AS [OrderId1],
    [Extent2].[Quantity] AS [Quantity],
    CASE WHEN ([Extent2].[ProductOrderId] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) ELSE 1 END AS [C1]
    FROM  [dbo].[Orders] AS [Extent1]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[ProductOrders] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[OrderId] = [Extent2].[OrderId]
    WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT
        1 AS [C1]
        FROM ( SELECT TOP (10) [c].[OrderId] AS [OrderId]
            FROM [dbo].[Orders] AS [c]
        )  AS [Limit1]
        WHERE [Limit1].[OrderId] = [Extent1].[OrderId]
    )
)  AS [Project2]
ORDER BY [Project2].[OrderId] ASC, [Project2].[C1] ASC
```

And now the subquery doing the `select top`is not ordered by `ClerkCode`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Your resulting SQL is not complete - your subquery is not returning a column and it should be `ORDER BY` instead of `ORDERBY`.  reduce your actual code down to a reasonable size (e.g. reduce the number of columns returned) so we can see the ACTUAL sql.

Comment: The actual SQL is huge, that is why I warned this is pseudo code.

Comment: But your pseudo-code SQL is not valid, so we have no way to know what the actual result is or how to change the code appropriately.

Comment: Of course it is not valid, is just expressing how the orderby is put out of the subquery, that is all. It is not need it to paste 1000 lines of sql.

Comment: I tried something like this in LinqPad, and it seems generate the SQL that you want.

Comment: I updated the post with real generated SQL from a simplified example. It seems the problem is the `.Distinct`

Comment: You're looking for distinct `OrderId` values? Wouldn't they already be distinct?

Comment: Yeah right, bad example :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The expected behavior is that it returns an unordered sequence of the unique items in source.

-- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348456

---

It's implementation dependent, but `Distinct` seems like it would clear any previously set ordering.

Comment: Thanks this explains it. I think the same thing happens with GroupBy. Cheers.